# Can't debug android app 'waiting to attach'

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio

I know there is a lot questions about that issue, I have read many of them but it still doens't work. I tried:

1. uninstall app on device
2. cleaning project
3. in manifest: android:debuggable="true"
4. in buils.grandle: debuggable:true
5. on device in developer options uncheck and check USB debugging
6. dev options: app to debug-> none
7. dev options: waiting for debugger check/uncheck
8. restart device, restart Android Studio
9. manifest: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_DEBUG_APP"></uses-permission>`

I don't remember what else I have done, I still cannot debug this app. I have create new app, simple HelloWorld and a can debug that so I suppose the problem is with my current app, not with AS. Please help me to find the problem, because I don't even know where to search for that.

Ubuntu 14.04 x64
Android Studio 1.1.0
Nexus 10 4.4.4 and Nexus 4 5.0.1 (real devices)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a different usb port. There are low and high energy ports. Be sure to connect to the second. This issue got me crazy debugging in Windows for many days.

Comment: OK, I found the solution, maybe it will help someone. in 'debug' tab on the left side is button (two red dots) named 'breakpoints'. There I checked 'Any exception enabled'. And it finally works!